# Relative Layout(with 2 textviews inside of it) inside a Linear Layout works - but i dont know why

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

I have been struggling to get this to work all day and finally got it to work by setting some margins(see code) but i do not know why it works

```
    //should this be a try/catch?
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Kefa.ttc");

    LinearLayout sampleLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    sampleLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sampleLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    sampleLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);

    TextView menuItemTitle = new TextView(this);
    menuItemTitle.setId(2);
    menuItemTitle.setText("All You Can Eat\t\t   $13.99");
    menuItemTitle.setTextSize(35);
    menuItemTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    menuItemTitle.setTypeface(tf);
    menuItemTitle.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 77, 30, 16));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams menuItemTitleParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    menuItemTitleParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //****why does setting the TOP margin work??****
    menuItemTitleParams.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
    menuItemTitle.setLayoutParams(menuItemTitleParams);

    TextView menuItemDesc = new TextView(this);
    menuItemDesc.setText("All you can ribs, chicken, pork and sides you can stomach to eat\n\tAlso includes dessert!");
    menuItemDesc.setTextSize(15);
    menuItemDesc.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    menuItemDesc.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 77, 30, 16));
    menuItemDesc.setLayoutParams(menuItemTitleParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams menuItemDescParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    menuItemDescParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //If i comment out the line of code below, the margin above still places the text
    //below the title.
    menuItemDescParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, menuItemTitle.getId());

    //##menuItemTitle.setLayoutParams(menuItemDescParams);
    menuItemDesc.setLayoutParams(menuItemDescParams);


    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams subMenuLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    subMenuLayoutParams.setMargins(400, 0, 400, 0);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(subMenuLayoutParams);

    relativeLayout.addView(menuItemTitle);
    relativeLayout.addView(menuItemDesc);

    sampleLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

    setContentView(sampleLinearLayout);
```

If i don't set the margins for the TOP of the menuItemTitle TextView the menuItemDesc Textview text lays right on top of the menuTitle text on the screen.

1. Why isnt my menuItemDescParams rule for BELOW not sufficent here?
2. If we didn't care about #1(which i do), why is expanding the TOP of the menuItemTitle margin move the menuItemDesc below the menuItemTitle textview?? If i comment out the line of code for BELOW, setting the margin still takes effect. Come to think of it i guess #1 is pretty important

Comment: ok i got it now - ## denotes that the code above should be change to menuItemDesc - i have edited it so that people can know how to do it if they are searching.

Comment: you should start writing your layouts in XML... it'll be much easier to make changes/understand your code later on :)

Comment: yeah i know if i would have made time to at least start with XML things might be easier but I dove in head first so to speak with and dove all the way to the bottom of the ocean. In this case i just copied and paste a variable name wrong - and everything worked. And as i have said before in other posts, the relative layout inside of my linear layout will be created dynamically so i had to opt for the programmatic approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this myself as noted in the comments